# Create basic library firebase error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have developed some applications using Firebase. Over time, I realized that I am repeating a lot of unnecessary code and decided to create a small library to help me increase productivity. Right at the beginning, I tried to create this object in Javascript:

```
read.childRoot = function(att) {
    var acessChildRoot = firebase.database().ref("root/");
    acessChildRoot.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        alert(snapshot.child("nome").val());
    });
}
```

And I tried to access through this line of code:

```
alert(read.childRoot("nome"));
```

So I was able to read the reference I wanted, but the first return was the undefined value. How can I filter this value and just display the value I really want to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want to wait for the first value to be set on a node.

In that case, I recommend using this snippet (from [my gist](https://gist.github.com/puf/146fecdae240ac0e62f858f7650aa85f)):

```
var listener = ref.on('value', function(snapshot) { 
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        console.log('Value is now '+snapshot.val());
        ref.off('value', listener);
    }
});
```